# Where to put utility functions

Tags: c++

I have `program.cpp` which contains `main` function. There is a class `Tracker` which is used in the `main` function. `program.cpp` also contains a bunch of utility functions (a function to check if the file passed as an argument to the program exists for example). I want to move these utility functions out of `program.cpp`. How should I do this:

- make `utils.cpp` containing the functions as they are, put the prototypes into `utils.h`, include `utils.h` inside `program.cpp` and compile as `g++ ... program.cpp utils.cpp`
- or, make `utils.h` a class with no private members, just have all the functions as public, implement them in `utils.cpp` and then use them in `program.cpp` as `Utils utils; utils.stuff(...);`

Comment: It completely depends on your decision, neither one is technically better IMHO.

Comment: or.. plan C, namespace if you need name-isolation. there are a lot of options open for you and none are really better or worse

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason to create a class if you don't need one (especially not just a class for a few unrelated functions). I would choose your first option, and declare the function prototypes as they are in `util.h`.

Comment: the only thing i can think of in favour of the class is it might be easier to tell that source for `utils.stuff(...);` is in `utils.cpp` as opposed to just `stuff(...);`

Comment: @zoran119: Your IDE should be able to immediately jump to the definition of a function, if you're looking at a call to it. So you don't really have to think about where it is. Believe me, when you're dealing with a couple million lines of somebody else's code, you're not going to remember where everything is. :)

Comment: This is a good use of namespaces then. Put them in a namespace called utils and then you can refer to them as utils::stuff(...)